# number_to_currency separator/delimiter issue 100{:separator=>",", :delimiter=>".", :raise=>true}000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I stumbled upon a quite annoying problem while using i18n.

When using:

```
<%= number_to_currency("100000000.123456") %>
```

I am getting on the screen:

```
100{:separator=>",", :delimiter=>".", :raise=>true}000{:separator=>",", :delimiter=>".", :raise=>true}000 €
```

HERE my locale yml:

```
number:
  currency:
    format:
      unit: "&euro;"
      precision: 0
      separator: " "
      delimiter: "."
      format: "%n&nbsp;%u"
```

I was using Rails 3.0.0rc, I have now upgraded to 3.0.9 the issue remains.

As suggested I removed format: "%n %u" from the locale file but the problem remains.

I am using i18n 0.5.0

Hope you can help,

Cheers,

joel

Answer (score 0):

Your locale yml should only have the format specified.

```
number:
  currency:
    format: "%n&nbsp;%u"
```

To set defaults for the other options, I would recommend using an initializer similar to how you'd set date formats.

config/initializers/default_currency_values.rb

```
ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper::DEFAULT_CURRENCY_VALUES.merge({
  :unit => "&euro;",
  :precision => 0,
  :separator => " ",
  :delimiter => "."
})
```